# Descending order by date filter with all CRUD operation in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with 100 rows and if i enter a new row its adds it and show on the top of the table as

```
<table class="table">
 <tr ng-repeat=" item in itemlist | orderBy:createdat:true">
<td>//code goes here</td>
<td><button ng-click="del(item)" class="fa fa-trash"></button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i have a delete button, but the problem is, when i delete any particular row its delete that particular row only but still show as that row is existing in the table till the page is get refreshed. So any idea.. It will be great help for me....
Here is the code.... just copy the code in plunker

In HTML

```
 <div ng-app>
 <div ng-controller="FooController">
<table>


    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'num':true">
        <td>{{item.num}} :: {{item.desc}}</td>
        <td><button class="fa fa-trash" ng-click="del($index)">
        delete
        </button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

in JS file

```
 function FooController($scope) {
$scope.items = [
    {desc: 'a', num: 1},
    {desc: 'b', num: 2},
    {desc: 'c', num: 3},
];
$scope.del=function(idx){
       $scope.items.splice(idx,1)
}
}
```

Comment: can you create plunker??

Comment: Too broad. Create a demo, maybe.

Comment: So, you have a bug in your code, and would like some help finding and fixing that bug. How could we do that without even seeing your code?

Comment: Its not bug dear,  and i m not saying to fix my bug, i m asking instead of such method do u have any other way. I dont want to show in desc but also want to delete particular row

Comment: You need to reload the array on the table, thats why only disappear when you refresh the page

Comment: So, the fact that you have to refresh the page to see the deletion is not a bug? It's the expected behavior? Why do you describe it as "a problem" then? I could provide "another way", if I knew "your way". But since it now seems that your unknown code does what you want it to do, I don't even know what you're asking anymore. Why use another way if your way works fine?

Comment: Here i m posting the example code copy in plunker, and check it

Comment: I have created plunker, but as i am new to stack, dont know how to post plunker. so i have edited the question check it

Comment: You have two different HTML code snippets. The first one is the one you should use: pass the item to delete, not the index. Passing the index will delete another element, since it's the index in the filtered, sorted collection, and the JavaScript code deletes from the non-filtered, non-sorted collection. I don't see why you would have to refresh the page to see an element disappear, though.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, but i tried it also, that doing the same thing. Fine can u let me know without knowing to end user how to refresh page/ that div.So there will be no problem.

Comment: As I said: you shouldn't have to refresh the page. Post a link to a plunkr reproducing the problem, and I'll be happy to diagnose the roblem and provide a fix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110707/discussion-between-ank-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 0):

HTML Part

```
   <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'num':true">
    <td>{{item.num}} :: {{item.desc}}</td>
    <td>
     <button class="fa fa-trash" ng-click="del(item)">
       delete
     </button></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Javascript Part

```
 $scope.items = [
{desc: 'a', num: 1},
{desc: 'b', num: 2},
{desc: 'c', num: 3},
];
$scope.del=function(idx){
   $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(idx),1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @S. Divya, Its working for me deleting the temporary data of an array. But in the same way i want it to delete from database. that is nothing but from factory. So i am searching for that.